# How can a c program can print exit() return value while it exits itself

Tags: c, printing, return, system-calls, exit

I am trying to print out the return code from exit() systemcall. But since program exits it doen not have a chance to print out something it will be killed. My question is that how can I print that return code in the program.

```
y = syscall(NR_mycall); //makes an exit in this second
printf("%s\n", strerror(y));
```

As expected no output! :U(

Comment: You cannot. Why do you want to?

Comment: Why? Sounds like an XY-problem! Your program passes the return code when calling `exit()` so why not print it *before*?

Comment: ask yourself: can I suicide and then go to the pub?

Comment: then how could I get that code?

Comment: You are passing status to exit() from code, This will be returned to OS from main()  of your program. At this stage you cannot print it. You can write another program just to check status of last executed program. No other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `exit()` from multiple places in your program, and you want to know which exit code was used in these exit calls, then instead of using `exit`, use `setjmp` in `main` and use `longjmp` in your code where there is now `exit` and pass the error/exit code in the `longjmp` call. Now main will know which exit/error code was used.

Answer (score 0):

You can't print the exit status. What I recommend is to check the exit status in your terminal with `echo $?` after executing a file which will print it. Or go to http://bashrcgenerator.com/ and make yourself a personal prompt and add the 'exit status' for you to see the exit status in your prompt everytime.